# Open source Indoor Turn-by-turn voice based Navigation in Android

Tags: android, navigation

Seen multiple projects for outdoor navigation. Specifically looking for indoor navigation SDK with provision to upload maps, mark source and destination PoIs and generate optimized routes between the PoIs. Once routes are generated and laid on the map, planning to use WiFi, BLE or UWB as positioning technology and can get position in centimeters, meters. Next the SDK should have provision for turn-by-turn navigation with voice prompts. Are there any open source Android projects for turn-by-turn navigation indoor for android platform? Please respond back.
Regards
Sandeep Suresh

Comment: Asking for libraries or tutorials is considered off-topic. Realize that all three methods you describe depend on radio waves which will be blocked by people/furniture/walls and in good conditions have a resolution of a meter or two. The best demo for 'high quality' indoor navigation was with the now dead [Project Tango](https://youtu.be/k43xJs3Roqg) which used IR cameras to orient the device in room space. Regardless good luck.

Comment: Thanks Morrison Chang for the response. We have the RF technology but looking into the turn-by-turn navigation Android SDK which is open source and can be leveraged.